# Install MATLAB on Ubuntu 17.10 - The following error was detected while installing 3p/icu_glnxa4:

Tags: software-installation, matlab

I've been trying to install MATLAB 2017a on my Ubuntu 17.10. I've had encountered several problems while installing, most importantly not being able to install as root, which was solved by another ask ubuntu post asking me to use 
`xhost si:localuser:root` 
and beginning the sudo operation as 
`sudo sh ./install -javadir /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/`. 
However, while the installation begins, I'm being thrown another error "archive is not a zip file". I've attached the image for your references,
[Matlab Installation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYuXO.png). 
Any help would be really appreciated thanks.

Comment: Hi Vijey, could you please post the contents of /tmp/mathworks_root.log?

Also, why do you want to install as root rather than as a normal user?

Comment: Here is the link to the log file "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ScJa3Wn2kSiae5yC1RSwauc8mC1P1LbZ". I'm trying to install as root, as it requires root permission to install its files in usr/local directory.

Comment: Looking at https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98459-why-do-i-receive-the-installation-error-archive-is-not-a-zip-archive?s_tid=gn_loc_drop - have you tried redownloading the installer?

The other thing you could try is running 'sudo chmod 777 /usr/local' but I wouldn't really recommend this on your primary system...